# How to add custom calculated column in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, calculated-columns

I have a SQL Server query as:

```
SELECT MD.Author_ID, MD.CoAuthor_ID, ACP.Probability [AC_Probability], 
       MD.Venue_ID, AVP.Probability [AV_Probability], A2P.pid [Paper_ID],
       P.abstract_research_area_category_id [Paper_Category_ID], 
       MD.Paper_Count, MD.Year
FROM   Merged_Data MD
JOIN   sub_aminer_author2paper A2P    ON MD.Author_ID = A2P.aid AND
                                      MD.Year      = A2P.p_year AND
                                      MD.Venue_ID  = A2P.p_venue_vid
JOIN   sub_aminer_paper P             ON MD.Venue_ID  = P.p_venue_vid AND
                                      MD.Year      = P.p_year
JOIN   AuthorCoAuthorProbability ACP  ON MD.Author_ID = ACP.Author_ID AND
                                      MD.CoAuthor_ID = ACP.CoAuthor_ID AND
                                      MD.Year      = ACP.Year
JOIN   AuthorVenueProbability    AVP  ON MD.Venue_ID = AVP.Venue_ID AND
                                      MD.Author_ID = AVP.Author_ID AND
                                      MD.Year      = AVP.Year
WHERE  MD.Author_ID = 677 AND 
       P.abstract_research_area_category_id IS NOT NULL AND 
       A2P.pid = P.pid
```

which give me results as:

[image]

I want to add another column i.e. `P_Probability` at end before `Year` column which should be calculated as for instance:

For `Year = 2005`, the `Author_ID = 677` has `8`, `11` and `12` in `Paper_Category_ID` column whereas `3` in `Paper_Count` column, also every `Year` has maximum 3 rows for each `Author_ID` if exists.

So value in `P_Probability` column should be:

Number of times `8` exists in those 3 rows for `677` against `2005` / `Paper_Count` = `1/3` = `0.333333333333333`
Number of times `11` exists in those 3 rows for `677` against `2005` / `Paper_Count` = `1/3` = `0.333333333333333`
Number of times `12` exists in those 3 rows for `677` against `2005` / `Paper_Count` = `1/3` = `0.333333333333333`

In other words the `P_Probability` calculation concept is:

Number of times `DISTINCT Paper_Category_ID` exists in 3 rows for an `Author_ID` in `Year` divided by `Paper_Count` in that `Year`

Comment: Create the query using `Outer Apply`. You can calculate the values in this section, it will be added as a column to the result set.

Comment: @wonderbell `Outer Apply` ?

Comment: @wonderbell How can we use `Outer Apply` ? What's this? Can you please explain

Comment: @Arulkumar can you try this?

Comment: Or should I go to write some code to do this task?

Comment: [Here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1958/sql-server-cross-apply-and-outer-apply/) is a nice description about `Apply`. Please show some code for what you are trying.